# PHPUnit test assert in object create

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

When I run phpunit I get:

> 1) FooTests::testException assert(): Assertion "false" failed

I would like to expect the assert in the case I have.

```
class FooTests extends WP_UnitTestCase {

  protected $foo;

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->foo = new Foo();
    }

    function testException() {
        // I'd like to expect an assert in the class foo so the test should not fail.  
        $this->foo->test();
    }
}

class Foo {
    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function __destruct(){}


    public function test(){
      assert('false');
    }

}
```

Comment: the behaviour is due to an exception rised from phpunit of the type: `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning`  which version of php are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve in one of the following manner:

**1) Catch the PHPUnit warning exception**

PHP emit a warning for each failed assertion, so PHPUnit raise an exception
of the type `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning`. As described in the [doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html):

> By default, PHPUnit converts PHP errors, warnings, and notices that
>   are triggered during the execution of a test to an exception.
>
> [..]
>
> `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice` and `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning`
>   represent PHP notices and warnings, respectively.

So you can simply catch in the following manner:

```
public function testException() {
    $this->expectException(\PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning::class);
    $this->foo->test();
}
```

**2) Using a callback on failed assertion**

You could do something more clear using the [assert_options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert-options.php), using as callback a custom exception and handle it as example:

```
public function test_using_assert_options_PHP5()
{
    $fnc = function() {
        throw new \Exception('assertion failed', 500);
    };

    $this->expectException(\Exception::class);
    $this->expectExceptionCode(500);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage('assertion failed');

    assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, $fnc);
    $this->foo->test();
}
```

**3) Change the  behaviour of the failing exception (only from PHP7)**

If you are using PHP7 you could implement this last behaviour with a new settings called [assert.exception](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.assert.exception):

```
public function test_using_assert_options_PHP7()
{
    $this->expectException(\AssertionError::class);
    assert_options(ASSERT_EXCEPTION, 1);
    $this->foo->test();
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you Matteo, that answer is perfect.  Option three worked like a charm!